# Rails3 nomethod error #<ActiveRecord::Relation>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a static page controller.
I get the menuname in the routes.rb and it's call the static controller show method.

> match '/:menuname' => 'static#show'

And static_controller.rb:

> @static=Staticpage.where("menuname =
>   ?", params[:menuname])

But if I want print @static.title in the view, I get this error:

> undefined method `title' for #

Whats wrong?

the SQL query looks good:

> SELECT `staticpages`.* FROM `staticpages` WHERE (menuname = 'asd')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of working alternatives:

```
@static = Staticpage.where("menuname = ?", params[:menuname]).first
@static = Staticpage.find_by_menuname(params[:menuname])
```